# Counting Number of Appearances with Multiple Conditions

Tags: spss

I'm trying to count the number of times an email appears in my data if it appears in Week 6. I'm currently using this code

```
if week=6 has6=1.
aggregate out=* mode=addvariables overwrite=yes/break=email /has6=max(has6).
aggregate out=* mode=addvariables /break=email /n=sum(has6).
```

This is working as expected but I left out one condition that I need. Email addresses can show up multiple times per week, but I only want to count once per week.

For example:

```
  Email            Week         N
jane@aol.com         6          2
bill@gmail.com       3          
bill@gmail.com       4         
sarah@hotmail.com    6          1
jane@aol.com         4          2
jane@aol.com         4          2
```

So even though jane@aol.com appears in the data three times, I only want her to show as N=2 because she appears only two times in different weeks (6 and 4). I do not want it to count her second instance in week 4 (which is what the current code is doing: She is being counted as a 3 because she appears three times).

So my two conditions are:

1. Only count email addresses that appear in Week 6 at least once.
2. Only count once per week.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will recreate the example data you gave:

```
data list list/email(a50) week(f1).
begin data
"jane@aol.com" 6
"bill@gmail.com" 3
"bill@gmail.com" 4
"sarah@hotmail.com" 6
"jane@aol.com" 4
"jane@aol.com" 4
end data.
```

First we'll identify each email that had week 6 at least once, and mark all it's occurences :

```
if week=6 has6=1.
aggregate out=* mode=addvariables overwrite=yes/break=email /has6=max(has6).
```

Now there are two ways to proceed.

First method: Second aggregate and reattach results to data:.

```
sort cases by email week.
dataset name orig.
dataset declare agg.
aggregate out=agg /break=email week/has6=max(has6).
dataset activate agg.
select if has6.
aggregate out=* mode=addvariables/break email/n=n.
dataset activate orig.
match files /file=* /table=agg /by email week.
exe.
```

Second method: Comparing rows to discount non-unique cases:

```
sort cases by email week.
compute countThis=has6.
if $casenum>1 and has6 and lag(email)=email and lag(week)=week countThis=0.
exe.
aggregate out=* mode=addvariables /break=email /n=sum(countThis).
```